# How much cost can i ask for website design to client?

Tags: project-bidding, project, small-projects

website design+choose images for banner + database for upload
missing child related website project contains 7 pages, i don't no how much can i ask.
so please help me to ask.

Answer (score 2):

1. Decide an hourly rate for yourself.
2. Estimate how much work-hour it may take for the job.
3. Consider any other expenses you want to cover.
4. Sum all to know how much you should ask.

   - hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Look at how much other people are charging. Compare your work with their work. Think about how much time it will take to complete and how much your time is worth. If the customer/client wants work done very quickly, normally you'd have to put other things on hold, so you'd charge more. Remember that you can actually speak with your customer about it, also. Your goal is for both of you to come out better off than you were without the deal. Your customer/client will appreciate this and might even send more business your way. Just make sure you stay professional about it and realistic to the market.